# How can I target the current menu item with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="a.html">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

This menu is being inserted into three files (`{a-c}.html`). Now I would like to use CSS to highlight the current menu item (A in `a.html`, B in `b.html`, and so on). The easy way out is to insert an additional class:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="a.html">A</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="b.html">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

But there’s no easy way to tell the generator code to add the `current` class where appropriate. I can easily tell the generator to add a class to the `body`:

```
<body class="a">…</body> <!-- in a.html -->
<body class="b">…</body> <!-- in b.html -->
<body class="c">…</body> <!-- in c.html -->
```

And then I can target the current menu item like this:

```
body.a li.a, body.b li.b, body.c li.c { /* highlight */ }
```

This works, but it feels like a hack. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: Good question, but I dont think we can handle this using only the css, we have to go for a small js code piece.

Comment: if javascript is an option, you could use that to determine whether current URL == link href and add the `current` class as appropriate. Not sure it's possible with pure CSS other than the ways you've described.

Comment: Looking at all the solutions below, it seems to me that your "hack" is just fine and quite a clean way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To further expand off of Mr. Alien's answer with a PHP based solution that I use...

If you generate your navigation using php, I set a variable equal to the pages title on each individual page.  Then I have an if statement that says in pseudo code...

IF the variable title of home equals the variable nav-label of home then apply the class of active.

So essentially at the very top of every one of my pages I first set that title variable like this:

```
<?php $title = "Home"; ?>
```

Then my navigation is generated and each LI is generated with this structure:

```
echo "<li class=\"$active\"><a href=\"$navPath\">$navLabel</a></li>";
```

Then my if statement:

```
if ($title == $navLabel) {
    $active = 'active';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add current class to respective menu for every html page. so it will target the respective menu, you are on which page.

here is example:

//CSS

```
ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;       
}
li a{
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.current{
    background: yellow;
}
```

//HTML for page a.html

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href=a.html" class="current">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

//HTML for page b.html

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href=a.html">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html" class="current">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

//HTML for page c.html

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href=a.html">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.html" class="current">C</a></li>
</ul>
```